# docker build - Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'll try build docker image with openvpn connect to HideMyAss VPN.
Look at Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y locales curl
RUN apt-get install -y php apache2 curl openvpn zip unzip bridge-utils
RUN apt-get install nano

RUN mkdir -p /dev/net && \
 mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200 && \
 chmod 600 /dev/net/tun && \
 cat /dev/net/tun

COPY tcp/Anguilla.TheValley.TCP.ovpn /etc/openvpn
COPY tcp/Angola.Luanda.TCP.ovpn /etc/openvpn
COPY tcp/Belgium.Brussels.TCP.ovpn /etc/openvpn
COPY tcp/pass.txt /etc/openvpn

EXPOSE 8888

RUN openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Belgium.Brussels.TCP.ovpn
```

When I try build this code I have an error:

```
cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state
```

But if I remove this 2 lines:

```
cat /dev/net/tun

RUN openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Belgium.Brussels.TCP.ovpn
```

than container successfully build and when I enter to him (docker exec) and run command

```
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Belgium.Brussels.TCP.ovpn
```

then all works fine.

Can somebody help me, why it doesn't work via image building?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all try to nest Dockerfile instructions to keep the layers up to a minimum (its known [best practice](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/))

For example instead of this:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y locales curl
RUN apt-get install -y php apache2 curl openvpn zip unzip bridge-utils
RUN apt-get install nano
```

Do like so

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y locales curl && \
    apt-get install -y php apache2 curl openvpn zip unzip bridge-utils && \
    apt-get install nano
```

So you will have only one RUN instruction therefore only one RUN layer in build image.

Secondly when you want to add default execution for running container use `CMD` instead of `RUN`. The main difference is that `RUN` is used during build to execute all the steps necessary to build an image and `CMD` is being executed after the container starts. Default docker entry point is `/bin/bash -c` but does not have a default command. `CMD` instruction passes whatever you put there to that entry point. Why am I saying this? Because you want to start openvpn after container startup, not during the build.

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing
>   container. These defaults can include an executable, or they can omit
>   the executable, in which case you must specify an ENTRYPOINT
>   instruction as well

Maybe silly question but why you need this part?

```
cat /dev/net/tun
```

Please try this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get clean && apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y locales curl && \
    apt-get install -y php apache2 curl openvpn zip unzip bridge-utils && \
    apt-get install nano && \
    mkdir -p /dev/net && \
    mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200 && \
    chmod 600 /dev/net/tun

COPY tcp /etc/openvpn

EXPOSE 8888

CMD openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/Belgium.Brussels.TCP.ovpn
```

!NOTE! There can be only one `CMD` instruction per Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: You cannot do that easily saldy... /dev if a specific folder that get wiped at the end of the build (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346114/why-cant-docker-build-copy-files-to-the-dev-folder/56346410#56346410).
When i try your code it fails at this command `mknod /dev/net/tun c 10 200` because /dev/net was not created :/
Do you have another solution?

Comment: @ImFonky Have you tried to use a script instead of starting openvpn directly, that first creates /dev/net and then calls mknod prior to starting openvpn?