# Why can't docker build COPY files to the /dev folder?

Tags: docker

I want to create a docker image where I add a file to the `/dev` folder. I'm using this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY test.txt /dev/
```

After building this with:

```
docker build -t test .
```

I get a docker image where nothing has been added to the `/dev` folder. No error has been thrown by `docker build`.

I find this very strange because copying to different folders works fine. For example

- `COPY test.txt /`
- `COPY test.txt /root/`
- `COPY test.txt /home/`

all work fine.

Does the `/dev` folder have some special permissions? How do I copy a file to the `/dev` folder?

I'm using [Docker Toolbox on windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/).

Comment: Why do you want to use the `/dev` folder? That one is a special folder which contains references to all devices?

Comment: See: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/165219/what-exactly-are-items-in-the-dev-directory

Comment: @k0pernikus I want to add a driver.more info https://github.com/EAIBOT/ydlidar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/dev` is a special folder on linux systems reserved to maintain the devices related ressources (filesystem, disks, etc...) and mounted on a special filesystem. In a docker container, it will be remounted with a tmpfs dedicated filesystem and is not on the main container filesystem (`/`). See the following example:

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04
root@17b9ad96ccbc:/# df -h /dev/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
```

In your case, your file was actually copied during the build but in a temporary filesystem that died as soon as the build was finished.

Conclusion: don't use `/dev` as a destination, choose an other folder.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator. Now I understand why the file file dissapeared whil no error was thrown

Answer (score 0):

I think `/dev` is mounted when the container is created, so if you really need it you can copy (or symlink) a file into it after that, e.g. on a `entrypoint.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

ln -s /app/my_virtual_device /dev/my_virtual_device

exec "$@"
```

Then reference it on the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ...

...

ENRTYPOINT ["bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```