# tun interface inside docker not able to read packets from host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, iptables, tun, mknod

I am trying [this tutorial](https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) for creating and using `tun` interface. In my case, I want to use it inside a docker container. My host and docker container both are Linux with mknod support. I am trying to get tun interface inside the container to read packets from host but without using `--network=host`.

Based on the [docker run doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities), I am mapping host `/dev/net/tun` inside docker using `--device`. Then adding capabilities `NET_ADMIN` (also tried adding `MKNOD`, `NET_RAW` but does not seem to help). Then using the example tun reader below; which is example from above tutorial; with code added to create interface; tried to read the packets.

It can read packets from ping on 10.0.0.2 from within the container. But not able to read from ping on host. With `--network=host` flag to `docker run`, the `tunx` interface is created on host and therefore ping works.

My question is, is there a to get it to work without using host network? Do I need any explicit `iptables` rules to forward traffic between container and host?

`tun_alloc` function is from [this tutorial](https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/)

**docker command**

```
docker run -it --device=/dev/net/tun:/dev/net/tun -cap-add=NET_ADMIN <image>
```

**reader code**

```
int main(void) {
  const char *ifname = "tunx";
  const char *ifaddr = "10.0.0.1/24";
  char tun_name[IFNAMSIZ];
  char buffer[2096];
  int tun_fd = -1;
  char cmd[1024] = "";
  int err = -1;

  strcpy(tun_name, ifname);
  tun_fd = tun_alloc(tun_name, IFF_TUN);  /* tun interface */
  if (tun_fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to alloc_tun. tun_fd: %d\n", tun_fd);
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("tun_fd: %d\n", tun_fd);

  printf("ip commands \n");

  snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "/bin/ip addr add dev %s %s", ifname, ifaddr);
  err = system(cmd);
  fprintf(stdout, "Running: %s, err: %d\n", cmd, err);
  if (err < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "failed system. Cmd:%s, err: %d (%s)\n", cmd, err, strerror(errno));
          exit(1);
  }

  snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "/bin/ip link set %s up", ifname);
  err = system(cmd);
  fprintf(stdout, "Running: %s, err: %d\n", cmd, err);
  if (err < 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "failed system. Cmd:%s, err: %d (%s)\n", cmd, err, strerror(errno));
          exit(1);
  }

  while (1) {
    /* Note that "buffer" should be at least the MTU size of the interface, eg 1500 bytes */
    int nread = read(tun_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    if(nread < 0) {
      perror("Reading from interface");
      close(tun_fd);
      exit(1);
    }

    /* Do whatever with the data */
    printf("Read %d bytes from device %s\n", nread, tun_name);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A specific goal of Docker is that container processes can't do host-global things like modify the network environment.  If you don't use `--network host` (and you generally shouldn't) a container will run in its own network namespace and the tunnel interface will be local to the container.  I'd run this process directly on the host and not in a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze Is there a way to limit container access to specific interface? Then maybe I can create tunx interface on host and limit my container access to that interface. I do not really need full access to host network, but just single tun interface.